# How to change default date format in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.5.x.

I have the following code in my controller;

```
$Dates = $this->Model->find('all');          
echo json_encode($Dates);
```

`$Dates` contain some dates with the default format being `YYYY-mm-dd`. How can I change it such that the format becomes `dd-mm-YYYY`?

Comment: I believe the only legit way, is to do it through a behavior, or convert it in an `afterFind()` in your `AppModel`

Answer (score 4):

```
$Date= $this->Date->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Date.created')));

foreach ($Date as $key => $value) {
   $date['date'] = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($value['Date']['created']));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($date);
```

**I have made a small demo in CakePHP and It works fine. I have written it in my controller. You should try it.**

Output :

**Array
(
    [date] => 30-09-2014
)**

You can set your date format as per you requirement.

Answer (score 1):

// You can change date format Using TimeHelper like

```
echo $this->Time->format('2011-08-22', '%d %m, %Y');
```

**Output**

22-08-2011

Answer (score 0):

```
$original_date = explode('/',$Dates);
$day= $original_date[0]; // 2014
$month = $original_date[1]; // 07
$year=  $original_date[2]; // 21
$date = $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year;
echo $date;
```